# How to restart a router with curl or wget to pass URL as well as POST parameters?

Tags: router, reboot, wget, curl

I have an Edimax router and from wireshark I see that the router restarts with the POST `http://192.168.2.1/goform/formReboot` and the form elements `reset_flag=0&submit-url=%2Fadmin_restart.asp`

Using `curl` and `wget` I have tried different methods of POST, but I have been unsuccessful. If I go directly to formReboot I get a 404 error. If I use POST I get an empty reply from server and no restart...

Here is an example:

```
curl -u 'admin:pass' --form 'reset_flag=0&submit-url=%2Fadmin_restart.asp' 'http://192.168.2.1/goform/formReboot
```

Answer (score 0):

The examples from the cURL command show that you separate the form entries using `;` instead of `&`. You might want to try that.

Also, `curl --verbose ...` will give you more details that might help you find out what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Just managed to reboot an Edimax/Medion MD86833 WLAN repeater using
`curl -u 'admin:pass' --form 'reset_flag=0&submit-url=%2Fcontool.asp' 'http://192.168.1.201/goform/formReboot'`

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this article the other day and it is one of the most perfectly explained and demonstrated ways to collect all the info you need to make the 2 calls youd need to a router with authentication. Using Chrome's developer tools you can see what is happening on your browser session while you're on your router and generate the curl commands you would need to execute almost any of the admin screens.

1. the 1st curl is to authenticate and generate an authentication cookie
2. the 2nd is the actual call to the router function passing in the cookie

https://ttytoast.io/use-siri-to-configure-your-asus-router-pt1/

For my router, my curls ended up being:

curl #1 to authenticate:

```
curl -c /tmp/cookie-jar.txt 'http://192.168.1.1/login.cgi' \
  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
  -H 'Cache-Control: max-age=0' \
  -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' \
  -H 'Origin: http://192.168.1.1' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36' \
  -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9' \
  -H 'Referer: http://192.168.1.1/Main_Login.asp' \
  -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9' \
   --data-raw 'group_id=&action_mode=&action_script=&action_wait=5&current_page=Main_Login.asp&next_page=index.asp&login_authorization=SuPeR_SeCrET_hAsH_FroM_cHrOmE'
```

*obviously "SuPeR_SeCrET_hAsH_FroM_cHrOmE" is not real. Yours will be unique ;-)

curl #2 to whichever link your trying to get to:

```
curl -b /tmp/cookie-jar.txt 'http://192.168.1.1/Advanced_LAN_Content.asp' \
  -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' \
  -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36' \
  -H 'Referer: http://192.168.1.1/index.asp' \
  --compressed
```

The doc is for an Asus router but really could work for almost any router.

**As good practice, you should curl the log out command to officially close the session too.